# Yabia Omer Online?

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, internet, hacham-ovadia-yosef

Does anyone know if it is possible to find the shu"t of Sefer Yabia Omer by R' Ovadia Yosef, online free?

Comment: hebrewbooks.org does not have it, however it has many other mid-to-late Twentieth Century Poskim available.

Comment: Thanks, @GershonGold, I actually was looking for a particular teshuva referenced on this site, to find the sources referenced.

Comment: http://www.tshuvos.com/

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Which one?

Comment: @Fred, Yabia Omer Yoreh Deah 10:4. The teshuva focuses on the usage of a dishwasher for both milchig and fleischig

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt [Here](http://www.kipa.co.il/community/show/7230969).

Comment: Hebrewbooks does not reprint anything that is under current copywrite.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I recall that responsum being from his shorter ones. OTOH his student, R. Pinchas Zabihi, wrote a lengthy resp. on this matter in his Ateret Paz (Vol 1 YD §4) and at the end cites R. Ovadia's approval of his outcome. *This* responsum is "online free" [here](http://www.bsd-paz.org/Texts/AteretPaz_v2_Yore_Dayah/html/E7ECF75FE05FEBF8EA5FE15FE9E5F8E45FE3F2E45FF1E9EEEF5FE35FE0E5FA5FE0.htm).

Answer (score 2):

The site [responsa.co.il](http://www.responsa.co.il/searchg/%D7%A9%D7%95%22%D7%AA%20%D7%99%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A2%20%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8%20%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7%20%D7%93%27%20%D7%97%D7%99%D7%95%22%D7%93%20%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F%20%D7%9B%D7%96_page15.aspx) has some of it; I'm unsure how to actually search that site. Maybe using `site:responsa.co.il` on Google.

Comment: From what I can gather from the [main page](https://www.responsa.co.il/home.en-US.aspx), you need to subscribe (i.e. pay a fee) to actually read anything. If you follow the "Browse" link at the top you can find the book, and browse it's outline, but when you select a particular section for text, the site asks you to log-in/sign-up.