# Rav Ovadia Yosef's Books Online

Tags: sources-mekorot, product-recommendation, internet, hacham-ovadia-yosef

Are any of Rav Ovadia Yosef's books available online?  I had run across his son's Yalkut Yosef online at one point, but forgot to bookmark it and was wondering if someone could point me to either one.

Comment: Search for `יוסף, עובדיה` in the "author" field at http://hebrewbooks.org.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38236/759

Answer (score 3):

The *Kitzur Shulchan Aruch Yalkut Yosef* is online [here](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01355.html).

Comment: I just noticed that it's not the whole Yalkut Yosef, it's Kitzur Yalkut, but I'll let you keep the +1 anyways :-)

Comment: The kitsur is also on http://www.yalkut.info/, is available as an [android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=il.yahadut.yalkutyosef&hl=en), is included in uvalechtecha baderech ([iPhone](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/onyourway-wblktk-bdrk-m-gr/id449507485?mt=8)|[android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=oyw.tnc&hl=en)|[www](http://mobile.tora.ws/))