# Using Dishwashers for both Meat and Milk

Tags: kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk, kashering-kosherization

Can one use a dishwasher to wash both meat and dairy dishes, either simultaneously or consecutively?  What about *pareve* dishes?

Answer (score 10):

Rav Ovadia Yosef permits meat and milk dishes at the same time if there is soap in the initial wash, but prefers that one only run them in separate cycles, as, he reports, does his son Rav Yitzchak Yosef (Yabia Omer YD 10:4).

Rav Yitzchak Abadi permits washing meat and milk dishes in separate cycles (Or Yitzchak YD 1:4 and 2:8).

Rav Shlomo Aviner permits washing meat and milk dishes in separate cycles (Sheilat Shlomo 1:311, 2:174, 3:135 quoted [here](http://www.havabooks.co.il/sms.asp?cat=87)).

Rav Dov Lior permits washing meat and milk dishes in separate cycles if you make sure the dishwasher is clean between runs (http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/60607).

Rav Yosef Kapach permits washing meat and milk dishes in separate cycles (quoted here http://www.tora.co.il/shiurim/tsuriel/p_kapach.doc).

It is my understanding that most of the Rashei Yeshiva in YU (including Rs Willig and Schachter) believe running an empty cycle between a meat load and a dairy load would be more than sufficient qua Kashrut (though whether routinely switching is good kitchen strategy is another discussion).

Badei Hashulchan (Beiruim 95 sv Shari) rules that if it has been 24 hours since the last use and the dishwasher (including the filter at the bottom) is cleaned of any residue, then one could be lenient, but he doesn't think such a cleaning of the filter is very practical and cautions against trying. (Anyone who has ever tried eating the guk from the filter may at this point be baffled.)

Comment: http://www.zomet.org.il/?CategoryID=198&ArticleID=287&Page=1#_Toc175559600

Comment: I know of several poskim who prohibit it (and one who goes so far as to insist that Rav Moshe and Rav Obadiah must have looked at a different type of dishwasher than the ones he has researched). Even if there's no way anyone would eat the "guk," it could still be nosein taam lishvach, no?

Comment: @Matt There is certainly a logical category of things which no one would eat which impact flavor positively. I still struggle to see how the guk is in that category.

Comment: http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=4552

Comment: Since this does a good job listing many of the opinions, it may help to add Rav Moshe Feinstein's opinion in.

Comment: @zeev his opinion and some of the issues with it are already noted on this page. I'm honestly not sure he was talking about the same things we have.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38236/yabia-omer-online#comment300764_38236

Comment: Interestingly, I heard today from R Avraham Yosef (ROY's son) on his radio program that one could use a dishwasher for *basari* and *halavi* dishes if the first washing cycle used **cold** water and washing powder, but not if using hot water. Maybe the nature of dishwasher has changed and requires this refinement.

Comment: @mbloch it is always wise to understand each rabbis reasoning and check your technology to see if it still applies. That's why we cylor

Comment: https://ph.yhb.org.il/04-11-07/

Comment: The linked lenient ruling of Rav Dov Lior seems to be only regarding where there is no dairy residue on the dishes placed in the dishwasher (which notably is not usually the case when one washes a load of dairy dishes).

Answer (score 5):

Igros Mosheh Yoreh Deah Orach Chaim 1 siman 104 & Yoreh Deah 2 siman 28 & 29 says you can use a dishwasher for both meat and dairy immediately one after another, but only when you have reserved racks, one for meat, and one for dairy.

He does say that there is room for a baal nefesh to be stringent and not rely on this.

Comment: Does he explain why one requires separate racks? I have a hard time conceiving of a reason...

Comment: Yes he does, but it's a really long tshuva So I'm not going to write it from memory, but I think he was worried some food particles will be stuck to the rack and then the other type of kli will touch it during its washing process.

Comment: Would one distinguish between modern dishwashers which no longer have electric heating elements and older ones which did? The change happened due to efficiency standards enacted after R"Mosheh's petira. There is no concern of food particles being "baked in" accidentally with modern dishwashers...

Comment: @user6591 Because the dishwasher can clean the dishes on the racks but not the racks themselves?

Comment: @Isaac his lomdus was using the shpritzing action vs touching. The water is still yad soledes so I don't know if the point you raise would matter. But again, don't trust my memory further than you can throw it.

Comment: @Double if there was a good particle stuck between the lady dish and the rack, when you take it out, what you are left with is a dirty dish in your cupboard which is a problem as far as your wife is concerned. You also have a dirty rack which is a problem when you put the other type of keli on it and run the cycle.

Comment: At most it's a question of iroy kli rishon, and most likely kli sheni. It would seem to depend highly on what temperature your water heater is set to, no? If I'm using "hot water," but my water only reaches 120 degrees (the standard setting), and then the water touching the dishes is BELOW that temperature, it would seem that we're well under yad soledes bo.

Comment: @user6591 Can't you just look at it and see if it's clean? Much easier than having two racks. That's what we rely on for Kashrut with pots (ie for Nat-bar-Nat vs b'ein, or for prepping for Hag'ala) all the time: visible inspection of cleanliness.

Comment: @Isaac dishwashers use the heating coil to heat to water too, Not just dry them. I don't know the working temperatures or how much They cool off, But he definitely addresses the irui issue, that's what I meant by shpritzing.

Comment: @user6591 Different dishwashers work differently regarding water heating.

Comment: @Double when the Igros Double AA comes out I hope to see the inspection suggestion.

Comment: @user6591 No need. RMF is already strongly questioned by later Achronim. I'm just giving you a hard time. I know you're just quoting.

Comment: @Double I'm not used to defending this side of the argument. Most of the people I know would never rely on this 'leniency'. Ah well.

Comment: @user6591 didn't Rav Moshe make a distinction between porcelain

Comment: @Sam Yes. But that was in regard to non kosher dishwasher. Here we are discussing kosher absorption.

Comment: https://seforimblog.com/2021/12/gelatin-supposed-retractions-and-abraham-goldstein-part-1/

Answer (score 3):

Chacham Ovadia Yoseph has a very important Teshuba (answer) granting permission for this in his book ‘Yabia Omer’ in Helek 10. There, he writes an opinion based on what Maran wrote in the Shulchan Aruch, in Yore De’Ah siman 95:4. Maran writes of the case where people wanted to use giant pots normally used for dairy cooking for the purpose of cleaning various tableware and cookware including meat dishes. Maran says that it would be permissible to use this giant dairy pot to clean meat dishes so long as a distasting agent such as ‘Efer’ (Ashes) or soap is added. Such an agent would render the milk in the walls of the pot ‘pagum’ (bitter, unsavory, unfit, spoiled), thus allowing the insertion of a meat vessel for cleansing. This leniency even applies if the meat pot is dipped in the giant milk pot together with boiling hot water.

Chacham Ovadia Yoseph applies Maran’s reasoning by the giant milk pot to permit simultaneous washing of meat dishes and dairy dishes in a dishwasher. The soap deposited into that designated compartment when released together with the hot water renders the dishwasher cavity ‘pagum’. Chacham Ovadia Yoseph therefore comes out that not only is it permissible to use the same dishwasher for both meat and dairy dishes, but it is also permissible for one dishwasher to be used to wash dairy and meat dishes simultaneously. This is also the opinion of Chacham Matloub Abadi in his Sefer ‘Magen Ba'adi’.

Source: https://www.dailyhalacha.com/displayRead.asp?readID=810

Comment: Well done! So R'Moshe says yes with a caveat (that may not apply) and R'Ovadia says yes ligamrei. Neat.