# Where can I get the index for Yabia Omer?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, hacham-ovadia-yosef

Where can I get the index for Yabia Omer ?
I cant find it anywhere since its out of print. Any ideas ?

Comment: Good luck finding one in the states been looking for one for 5yrs already. Let me know if you find it

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38236/yabia-omer-online

Answer (score 2):

You may want to hold out and see if they update it with the Teshuvot from vol. 11, but it's available in Eretz Yisrael seemingly.
http://www.sefer.org.il/Product/41188/share

Comment: Out of stock at provided link; as is elsewhere.

Comment: My mistake. I read the description but not the stock quantity

Answer (score 1):

Updated information for those who are still looking. Just reprinted last year.

https://seforimcenter.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=13854&strReferer=search&PPGR=0

Comment: When I click, it says out of stock (on the right side)

Comment: @mbloch They changed it because I just ordered one.

Comment: Now watch I will get an email notification that the sefer was actually out of stock. I have also been looking for the indexes for quite a while. I can’t believe the person who holds the copyright doesn’t reprint. There are a ton of people who have been looking for this for a while.

Answer (score 1):

It is [widely] available, see [here on Zbermanbooks](https://zbermanbooks.com/%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%99%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A2-%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8-%D7%99%D7%97%D7%95%D7%94-%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%AA-%D7%97%D7%96%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%91%D7%93%D7%99%D7%94).